# SP Provider Hosted addin vs debugger stops when we run application

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, visual-studio-2015

It happens very often that when every time that when  i try hit F5 in VS2015 after all the steps are done, VS will opens browser and stops all of a sudden.
will get below error as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

also tried [Provider Hosted application often stops debugging](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121796/provider-hosted-application-often-stops-debugging#)

[Debugger stops during debug session](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11811/debugger-stops-during-debug-session)